# Sockets: Why does my message from the server always get split up into the exact same 2 messages?

Tags: java, php, sockets, websocket, phpwebsocket

**This php snippet is on the server-side:**

```
if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) 
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";


//bind the socket to the ip address and port
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) 
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";  

//make the socket listen for connections, SOMAXCONN is the max limit of queued sockets waiting to 
//connect
if (socket_listen($sock, SOMAXCONN) === false) 
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";

if (($client= socket_accept($sock)) === false) 
    echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";

if ( false === ($id = socket_read($client, 10, PHP_NORMAL_READ)) )
    socket_close( $client ); //close the socket connection

$talkback = "PHP: Your id is '$id'.\n";
socket_write($client, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
```

**This java snippet is on the client-side:**

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    Log.i( "MY_TAG", "Message received: " + inputLine);
```

Where `inputLine` is a String, and `in` is the inputstream of my client-side socket.

**The output is ALWAYS:**

`Message received: Your id is '1`

`Message received: '.`

Comment: show how you opened the socket?

Comment: `$id = "1\n"` possibly?

Comment: @MarcB I've added it.  I've included only the necessary code that I think you guys need to see, but let me know if you need to see more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the `$id` from the socket and in `PHP_NORMAL_READ` reading is terminated by a newline, so `$id == "1\n"`.  Just `trim()` it:

```
$id = trim($id);
//or
$talkback = "PHP: Your id is '" . trim($id) . "'.\n";
```

Comment: I realized it as soon as I did the var_dump like you suggested.
Thank you.